# When exactly is the operator keyword required in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, operator-overloading

In the [14th Kotlin Koan](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Conventions/Comparison/Task.kt) on operator overloading, I was suprised when after solving I viewed the answer and saw that the `operator` modifier was **not** required on the `compareTo` method:

```
data class MyDate(val year: Int, val month: Int, val dayOfMonth: Int) : Comparable<MyDate> {
    override fun compareTo(other: MyDate) = when {
        year != other.year -> year - other.year
        month != other.month -> month - other.month
        else -> dayOfMonth - other.dayOfMonth
    }
}
```

The [operator overloading docs](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html) linked to from the exercise explicitly says:

> Functions that overload operators need to be marked with the operator
>   modifier.

So what's going on here?  Why does this code compile?  When exactly is `operator` required?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Why does this code compile?

This compiles because the overridden interface method, [`Comparable<T>.compareTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-comparable/compare-to.html), is itself an `operator fun`.

```
/**
 * Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns zero if this object is equal
 * to the specified [other] object, a negative number if it's less than [other], or a positive number
 * if it's greater than [other].
 */
public operator fun compareTo(other: T): Int
```

As the function overrides this, it is also an operator function.

> When exactly is `operator` required?

`operator` in general is required whenever you wish to be able to use a function as if it were an operator, since operator usages are simply compiled to function calls (except on primitive types, etc.)

That is, `foo += bar`, for example, is equivalent to `foo.plusAssign(bar)`, `foo[bar] = baz` is equivalent to `foo.set(bar, baz)`, etc.

Personally I prefer specifying `operator` wherever possible even if it is not required, for readability reasons.

If `MyDate` were *not* a `Comparable`, and you omitted the `operator` modifier, comparing two dates via `<`, `>`, `<=`, or `>=` would not compile.

I couldn't find anything in the [specification](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/operator-overloading.html#operator-overloading) on this, though. However in a polymorphic sense it makes sense - why should you be able to write `a < b` where the type of `a` and `b` are `Comparable`s, but not when they are a `MyDate`? Since you wouldn't be able to remove the "operator-ness" of this function, it makes sense that `operator` should be inheritable from the superclass method.

Comment: > whenever you wish to be able to use a function as if it were an operator < Correct, but not only this: the `getValue`/`setValue`/`provideDelegate` operators don't have an operator form. I'd rather say it's the keyword for functions that have another convention they can be called with.

Comment: > inferrable from the superclass method < 
it's rather inheritable than inferrable

Answer (score 8):

Kotlin has many features that are enabled via particular **conventions**. Those can be identified by the use of an `operator` keyword. Examples are *ranges*, *operator overloads,* *index operators*, *destructuring declarations* and more.

If we want to compare two objects in Java, for sorting e.g., we implement the `Comparable` interface with its `compareTo` method. This is also done in Kotlin, but with much better support and a shorthand syntax. If you implement this method in a class, you can use all the nice operators like `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=` with that class out of the box. These operators are translated to appropriate calls of `compareTo` by the compiler:

`obj1 > obj2` ⇒ `obj1.compareTo(obj2) > 0`

[The interface method `compareTo` in `Comparable`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-comparable/compare-to.html) already defines the `operator` keyword, which makes it redundant to add the keyword in your own implementation.

**In your example, the `operator` keyword is not mandatory since the overridden method already defines it.**

Answer (score 8):

In Java, operators are tied to specific Java types. For example, String and numeric types in Java can use the + operator for concatenation and addition, respectively. No other Java type can reuse this operator for its own benefit. Kotlin, on the contrary, provides a set of conventions to support limited Operator Overloading.

Let’s start with a simple data class:

```
data class Point(val x: Int, val y: Int)
```

We’re going to enhance this data class with a few operators.

In order to turn a Kotlin function with a pre-defined name into an operator, we should mark the function with the operator modifier.  For example, we can overload the “+” operator:

```
operator fun Point.plus(other: Point) = Point(x + other.x, y + other.y)
```

This way we can add two Points with “+”:

> > val p1 = Point(0, 1)
> >
> > val p2 = Point(1, 2)
> >
> > println(p1 + p2)
> >
> > Point(x=1, y=3)

Comment: This does not even address the question, let alone answer it. The OP didn't ask about what operator overloading in Kotlin is, but about why his code that apparently required the "`operator`" keyword still compiled and worked as intended without it.

Comment: Thanks, you eliminated the further questions in my mind.